# Wordpress logging requests into a database

Tags: wordpress, http, plugins, request

I am trying to create a plugin which logs http requests from users into a database. So far I've logged the requests for php files by hooking my function to the init function. But now I want to know if I can also log requests for files such as images, documents, etc. Is there any php code executed when someone requests files? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default, no. The normal mod_rewrite rules (not to be confused with WP's own rewrite rules) Wordpress uses specifically exclude any existing files such as images, css or javascript files. Those will be handled directly by Apache.

You obviously could add a custom script that runs on each request, logs the access to the database, reads those files and prints their content to the client, but it would come at a considerable cost, I'm afraid.
Apache, albeit not the fastest webserver around, is much, much faster in delivering a file to a client than running a php script, setting up a database connection, logging etc pp would be.

You'd get much higher server load, and probably noticeably slower page loads.

Instead, I recommend that you parse the access logs. They'll most likely contain all of the data you're looking for, and if you have access to the configuration, you can add specific headers sent by the client. You can easily do this with a cronjob that runs once a day, and it doesn't even have to run on the same server.

Comment: Can I make apache also log the cookies sent by the browser? I need the cookie too but it doesn't appear in that log. And do you have any ideea how could I make a script which executes each time de access.log modifief its content? Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Yes, you can log the cookie. See [mod_log_config's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html): `%{VARNAME}i` logs headers, so `%{Cookie}i` should work (or `%{COOKIENAME}c` if you only want a specific cookie). As for reacting to changes, you'd probably want a script that continously runs and works like the `tail` command in linux (or just use `tail -f`, [as suggested here](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-tail-file-php)).